# Entra multitenant collaboration

Tags: azure, multi-tenant, entra

In the multitenant collaboration users from first tenant are unable to find guest users from second tenant.

i have been setup cross tenant sync and B2B direct collaboration but however guest users don't find between these 2 tenants.